# Show that 3 vectors expand $\Bbb R^2$

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

I am studying for my reexamination. I failed the first try and I have a really hard time understanding most of linear algebra. But I am working as hard as my head can.

I have the vectors shown as
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
    1        \\
    1      
\end{pmatrix}
, 
\begin{pmatrix}
    -1      \\
    -2       
\end{pmatrix}, 
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
    2      \\
    0      
\end{pmatrix}

I need to show that these three vectors expand the vector space $\Bbb R^2$ and I don't know how to show that the right way.

I hope someone can help me.

Comment: Please show your thinking , thanks!

Comment: I assume by "expand" you mean "span". If so, given $x,y \in \mathbb{R}$ can you find numbers $a,b,c \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $av_1+bv_2+cv_3 = (x,y)$, where $v_1,v_2,v_3$ are the three given vectors?

These numbers $a,b,c$ will obviously have to depend on $x,y$.

Comment: Compute the determinant of each matrix $[v_i ~ v_j]$ where $v_i$ and $v_j$ are two different vectors of the list.

Comment: After taking the sum of the first two vectors we get $0\choose -1$ which we keep and throw the first two away. What space is spanned by $0\choose -1$ and $2\choose 0$? Hint: it is the same as the one spanned by $1\choose 0$ and ${0\choose 1}\,.$

Comment: @user1176589 Yes, you're right - sorry. It's my first time here, and to be honest I didn't have much to go on other than to form the matrix of the vectors and reduce it. I will provide more info of my thinking in the future.

Comment: @Pandir Yes, that makes sense when I look at the answer below. Thanks!

Comment: @nicomezi Aaah, that hadn't occured to me. I will give that a try as well. Thanks!

Comment: @KurtG. Yeah I can see that makes sense now. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $v_1 = (1,1) , v_2 = (-1, -2), v_3 = (2, 0) $

And let $P = (x, y) $ be any point in $\mathbb{R}^2$, then if the three given vectors span $\mathbb{R}^2$ we can always find at least one triple $(c_1, c_2, c_3)$ such that

$ c_1 v_1 + c_2 v_2 + c_3 v_3 = P $

In matrix-vector form, this translated into the system

$\begin{bmatrix} 1 && -1 && 2 \\ 1 && -2 && 0 \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} c_1 \\ c_2 \\ c_3 \end{bmatrix} =  \begin{bmatrix} x \\ y \end{bmatrix} $

always have a solution $(c_1, c_2, c_3) $.  The augmented matrix of the above system is

$\begin{bmatrix} 1 && -1 && 2 && x \\ 1 && -2 && 0 && y \end{bmatrix} $

Upon Gauss-Jordan elimination to transform this into reduced-row echelon form it becomes

$\begin{bmatrix} 1 && 0 && 4 && 2x-y \\ 0 && 1 && 2 && x-y \end{bmatrix} $

So by selecting $c_3 = t $ for an arbitrary $ t \in \mathbb{R} $ we can solve for $c_1 $ and $c_2 $ as follows:

$c_1 = (2x - y) - 4 t $

$c_2 = (x-y) - 2 t $

And this means there is an infinite number of ways we can express $P$ as a linear combination of $v_1, v_2, v_3$.  Hence, these vectors span $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Comment: Thank you very much, this helps me! I am a bit unsecure about the reduced-row echelon. When I try my self, I end up with:
1. row: 2x-y
2. row: x-y

Comment: Thanks. Yes,  you're right,  error corrected.

Comment: @StefanBondeNielsen  If my answer solves your problem, I would appreciate if you upvote it and accept it by clicking on the icons on the left top corner of my answer.

Comment: Great, then I can proceed, thank you again! And thank you for the guiding in upvoting and more - I might just learn it one day.

Comment: @StefanBondeNielsen Thank you.  I have upvoted your question, but some other user gave it a down vote, that's why it showing 0 votes.

Comment: Okay, thank you. Do you know why it might have gotten a down vote? I'm just curious so I can at least set up a more correct problem next time.

Comment: I am not sure why, but my guess is that what the community members are looking for, is more detail about what you tried and where you failed.  In short, more details.  So in your future questions, make sure to add as much detail as possible, and if you have links to related work that would be even better.

Comment: Good feedback - Thank you very much!